# Concatenate TEXT, format only parses positive numbers

Tags: excel-formula

I want to concatenate three different cells into one to make a nice table presenting average and maximum value and the number of observations as follows:

1.234 - 3.456 ( 7 )

I found a way to do this, probably not the most efficient but still. However the only downside is that there are also negative numbers, which are for some reason ignored.

The formula I use is the following:

```
=IF(R[-24]C>1;CONCATENATE(TEXT(R[-8]C;"#,##0;;@")&" - "&TEXT(R[-16]C;"#,##0;;@")&" ( "&R[-24]C&" )");CONCATENATE(TEXT(R[-16]C;"#,##0;;@")&" ( 1 )"))
```

So my question would be, is there something I'm doint wrong with "#,##0;;@" or is there some error in my concatenate?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `CONCATENATE()` when you're already doing the concatenation with the ampersand symbol (`&`)

Comment: The second part of your format string (between the two `;;`) is blank, which means hide negative values.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, what should go there to not hide negative values. I just found this bit of code from the internet, so don't really know how this works.

Comment: @MacroMan good point, I could change the ampersand to a ; and it works as the real concatenate formula. Would there be any difference in the workings anyway?

Comment: @Luuklag no difference, just a matter of readability. The problem your facing is casued by your custom format as identified by chris neilson

Comment: I did some looking around, and I think that replacing ;; by ; should fix the problem, or otherwise just remove ;; in total.

Answer (score 0):

Further to chris neilsen, [Create or delete a custom number format](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4) has:

> A number format can have up to four sections of code, separated by
> semicolons. These code sections define the format for positive
> numbers, negative numbers, zero values, and text, in that order.
>
> `<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>`
>
> For example, you can use these code sections to create the following custom format:
>
> **`[Blue]#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00);0.00;"sales "@`**

You are not requiring colours and seem not to need formatting for other than numbers so you might prefer something like:

```
'=IF(R[-24]C>1,TEXT(R[-8]C,"#.##0;-#.##0;0")&" | "&TEXT(R[-16]C,"#.##0;-#.##0;0")&" ( "&R[-24]C&" )")
```

though this is **before** any adjustment required for your configuration (list delimiter).

Since using parentheses for the number of observations I have avoided them for negatives and because the hyphen then might look odd I have changed that to pipe (and also 'rationalised' the mix of `CONCATENATE` and `&` as mentioned by @Macro Man).